Issues fetching data from Firestore in Flutter without prior authentication
I'm developing a Flutter app using Firebase Firestore and I'm encountering a specific issue.
In my app, I have a method FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection').get() that is supposed to fetch data from Firestore. However, this method does not retrieve data unless I have previously used _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword in another view for optional login.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Are you getting any errors when you have unauthenticated Firestore calls?

Please check your firestore rules. If the rules say that "allow read, write: if auth!=null;" tehn it means only authenticated users can access the database. To allow you can put in the rules "allow read, write: if true;". It is not preferred though to make unauthenticated calls.

@YashasMajmudar  my Firestone rules are setting as  allow read, write: if true;

Is there any error? If yes a screenshot would help.
